# Cryptopp Ephemeral Diffie Hellman to C# Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, bouncycastle, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to convert cryptopp DiffieHellman 2 key agreement method to c# bouncy castle library.

Here is the help page about cryptoo c++ library: http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Diffie-Hellman

I'm trying to implement RFC 5114's 1024-bit MODP group to C#.

But there are a lot of problems I couldn't solve.

1. When keyPair generates a key, it is 131 bytes, but it must be 128 bytes, because server sending to me 256 bytes key with static and ephemeral key. I must send 256 bytes too .But 1-, 2-, and 3-byte values are static in every key so I'm removing first 3 bytes in keys is it true?
2. Which secret key must I use for converting shared secret to other encryption system keys?
3. Example I have a secret key, how can I convert it for Twofish, RC6, xTEA, Serpent etc?

Here is my code:

```
    public byte[] CreateaNewDiffieHellmanKey()
    {
public static string Phex = "B10B8F96A080E01DDE92DE5EAE5D54EC52C99FBCFB06A3C69A6A9DCA52D23B616073E28675A23D189838EF1E2EE652C013ECB4AEA906112324975C3CD49B83BFACCBDD7D90C4BD7098488E9C219A73724EFFD6FAE5644738FAA31A4FF55BCCC0A151AF5F0DC8B4BD45BF37DF365C1A65E68CFDA76D4DA708DF1FB2BC2E4A4371";
public static string Ghex = "A4D1CBD5C3FD34126765A442EFB99905F8104DD258AC507FD6406CFF14266D31266FEA1E5C41564B777E690F5504F213160217B4B01B886A5E91547F9E2749F4D7FBD7D3B9A92EE1909D0D2263F80A76A6A24C087A091F531DBF0A0169B6A28AD662A4D18E73AFA32D779D5918D08BC8858F4DCEF97C2A24855E6EEB22B3B2E5";
public static string Qhex = "F518AA8781A8DF278ABA4E7D64B7CB9D49462353";

        BigInteger P = new BigInteger(Phex, 16);
        BigInteger G = new BigInteger(Ghex, 16);
        BigInteger Q = new BigInteger(Qhex, 16);

        IAsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator staticKeyGen = GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyPairGenerator("DH");
        IAsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator ephemeralKeyGen = GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyPairGenerator("DH");

        DHParameters dhParams = new DHParameters(P, G, Q, 0, 160);

        DHP = dhParams;

        KeyGenerationParameters kgpSt = new DHKeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), dhParams);
        KeyGenerationParameters kgpEp = new DHKeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), dhParams);
        staticKeyGen.Init(kgpSt);
        ephemeralKeyGen.Init(kgpEp);

        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair staticKeyPayir  = staticKeyGen.GenerateKeyPair();
        staticKeyEgri = AgreementUtilities.GetBasicAgreement("DH");
        staticKeyEgri.Init(staticKeyPayir.Private);

        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair ephemeralKeyPair  = ephemeralKeyGen.GenerateKeyPair();
        ephemeralKeyEgri = AgreementUtilities.GetBasicAgreement("DH");
        ephemeralKeyEgri.Init(staticKeyPayir.Private);

        AsymmetricKeyParameter StaticPublicKey = staticKeyPayir.Public;
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo StaticPublicKeyinfomuz = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(StaticPublicKey);
        byte[] st1 = StaticPublicKeyinfomuz.PublicKeyData.GetBytes();
        byte[] staticPublic = new byte[128];

        Array.Copy(st1, 3, staticPublic, 0, staticPublic.Length);

        AsymmetricKeyParameter EphPublicKey = staticKeyPayir.Public;
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo EphPublicKeyinfomuz = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(EphPublicKey);
        byte[] ep1 = StaticPublicKeyinfomuz.PublicKeyData.GetBytes();
        byte[] ephemeralPublic = new byte[128];

        Array.Copy(ep1, 3, ephemeralPublic, 0, ephemeralPublic.Length);

        return Bot.Birleştir(staticPublic, ephemeralPublic); // Combine 2 byte arrays

    }


    public bool AgreeTheKey(byte[] buffer)
    {

            byte[] staticpublic = new byte[128];
            byte[] ephemeralpublic = new byte[128];

            Array.Copy(buffer, 0, staticpublic, 0, staticpublic.Length);
            Array.Copy(buffer, staticpublic.Length, ephemeralpublic, 0, ephemeralpublic.Length);

            ICipherParameters istatic = new KeyParameter(staticpublic);
            ICipherParameters iphemeral = new KeyParameter(ephemeralpublic);

            DHPublicKeyParameters dhkpST = new DHPublicKeyParameters(new BigInteger(staticpublic), DHP);
            DHPublicKeyParameters dhkpEP = new DHPublicKeyParameters(new BigInteger(staticpublic), DHP);

            SharedStatic = staticKeyEgri.CalculateAgreement(dhkpST).ToByteArray();
            SharedEphemeral = ephemeralKeyEgri.CalculateAgreement(dhkpEP).ToByteArray();

            byte[] Sharedkey = SharedStatic;


          return true;



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have the added encoding, you may always cast from `AsymmetricKeyParameter` to `DHPublicKeyParameters` and retrieve Y using `getY()`. Of course, after getting the value as an integer, you may still want to encode it to a fixed number of octets (bytes). In general, unsigned, left padded big endian encoding is used for the numbers.

Comment: So now, when i send the key to the server, i must encode this key with big-endian right ?
How can i encode this key, can you give me example code thanks.